Micropython control stepper motor problem
I use the above packaged motor control library to control the stepper motor, but after I set the driver to 6400, the set speed and acceleration have no obvious effect, and the speed is always very slow. But when I set it to 200, it is very fast. What is the reason? I am using the stm32f407ZGT6 development board. The following is the motor control library.
import machine
import math
import time

class Stepper:
    def __init__(self, step_pin, dir_pin, en_pin=None, steps_per_rev=200, speed_sps=10, accel_spss=50, invert_dir=False, timer_id=-1):
        if not isinstance(step_pin, machine.Pin):
            step_pin = machine.Pin(step_pin, machine.Pin.OUT)
        if not isinstance(dir_pin, machine.Pin):
            dir_pin = machine.Pin(dir_pin, machine.Pin.OUT)
        if (en_pin is not None) and (not isinstance(en_pin, machine.Pin)):
            en_pin = machine.Pin(en_pin, machine.Pin.OUT)
                 
        self.step_value_func = step_pin.value
        self.dir_value_func = dir_pin.value
        self.en_pin = en_pin
        self.invert_dir = invert_dir

        self.timer = machine.Timer(timer_id)
        self.timer_is_running = False
        self.free_run_mode = 0
        self.enabled = True

        self.target_pos = 0
        self.pos = 0
        self.steps_per_sec = speed_sps
        self.max_speed = speed_sps
        self.acceleration = accel_spss  
        self.current_speed = 0
        self.steps_per_rev = steps_per_rev
        
        
    def speed(self, sps):
        self.max_speed = sps  
        self.steps_per_sec = sps  
    
    def speed_rps(self, rps):
        self.speed(rps * self.steps_per_rev)

    def set_acceleration(self, accel):
        self.acceleration = accel
    
    def target(self, t):
        self.target_pos = t

    def rela_target(self,t):
        self.target_pos = self.pos + t

    def target_deg(self, deg):
        self.target(self.steps_per_rev * deg / 360.0)
    
    def target_rad(self, rad):
        self.target(self.steps_per_rev * rad / (2.0 * math.pi))
    
    def get_curSpeed(self):
        return self.current_speed

    def get_pos(self):
        return self.pos
    
    def get_pos_deg(self):
        return self.get_pos() * 360.0 / self.steps_per_rev
    
    def get_pos_rad(self):
        return self.get_pos() * (2.0 * math.pi) / self.steps_per_rev
    
    def overwrite_pos(self, p):
        self.pos = p
    
    def overwrite_pos_deg(self, deg):
        self.overwrite_pos(deg * self.steps_per_rev / 360.0)
    
    def overwrite_pos_rad(self, rad):
        self.overwrite_pos(rad * self.steps_per_rev / (2.0 * math.pi))

    def step(self, d):
        if d > 0:
            if self.enabled:
                self.dir_value_func(1 ^ self.invert_dir)
                self.step_value_func(1)
                self.step_value_func(0)
            self.pos += 1
        elif d < 0:
            if self.enabled:
                self.dir_value_func(0 ^ self.invert_dir)
                self.step_value_func(1)
                self.step_value_func(0)
            self.pos -= 1

    def _timer_callback(self, t):

        if self.free_run_mode > 0:
            self.step(1)
        elif self.free_run_mode < 0:
            self.step(-1)
        elif self.target_pos > self.pos:
            self.step(1)
        elif self.target_pos < self.pos:
            self.step(-1)

        if self.current_speed < self.max_speed:
            self.current_speed += self.acceleration * (1/ self.steps_per_sec)
            self.current_speed = min(self.current_speed, self.max_speed)  
        elif self.current_speed > self.max_speed:
            self.current_speed -= self.acceleration * (1/ self.steps_per_sec)
            self.current_speed = max(self.current_speed, self.max_speed)

        if self.current_speed > 0:
            self.timer.deinit()  
            self.timer.init(freq=max(self.steps_per_rev, int(self.current_speed)), callback=self._timer_callback)
            # self.timer.init(freq=64000, callback=self._timer_callback)

    
    def free_run(self, d):
        self.free_run_mode = d
        if self.timer_is_running:
            self.timer.deinit()
        if d != 0:
            self.timer.init(freq=self.steps_per_sec, callback=self._timer_callback)
            # self.timer.init(freq=64000, callback=self._timer_callback)
            self.timer_is_running = True
        else:
            self.dir_value_func(0)

    def track_target(self):
        self.free_run_mode = 0
        self.current_speed = 0  
        if self.timer_is_running:
            self.timer.deinit()
        self.timer.init(freq=int(self.steps_per_sec), callback=self._timer_callback)
        # self.timer.init(freq=64000, callback=self._timer_callback)
        self.timer_is_running = True

    def stop(self):
        self.free_run_mode = 0
        if self.timer_is_running:
            self.timer.deinit()
        self.timer_is_running = False
        self.dir_value_func(0)

    def enable(self, e):
        if self.en_pin:
            self.en_pin.value(e)
        self.enabled = e
        if not e:
            self.dir_value_func(0)
    
    def is_enabled(self):
        return self.enabled


I hope someone can help me figure out what the problem is. Thanks

Because it takes a lot longer to move 6400 steps than it does to move 200. Pick the resolution the you actually need, 360 is probably a good place to start. It depends on what this is for. At 6400 you are cutting one degree into 17+ steps.

I need to count every step on my end, so using 360 degrees as the basis may not be appropriate.

Regardless of what you use, more steps equals more time. There is no way around that.

I use pyb Timer tested it and found that my freq was set very high, and I also set the resolution of the driver to 6400. Its speed is very fast, but I don't know how to count the number of pulses I send. But with the above library, even if I set the resolution of the drive to 6400 and the corresponding freq to 6400, it keeps going around 1000Hz. Why is this?

There will be a limit to the maximum pulse rate that the code is able to output.
